# Почему не открывается скрипт?

Tags: apache, php

Установил PHP 5.3.5 и параллельно xampp (Apache, MySQL, FileZilla). Но вот в чем дело: не открывает скрипт. Делаю так, как написано в книге, но ничего не выходит. Что я мог сделать не так?

Comment: Ставьте Денвер и не парьтесь. Простая и понятная установка, сам с первого раза разобрался

Comment: Учусь под чутким руководством брата(проблемы решаю сам)
Говорит Denwer слишком простой учись на xampp
Уже проблемы нет.Со всем разобрался.
Большое Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут вот какое дело: во-первых, какая ОС? Во-вторых: "из коробки", инсталлятор XAMPP сам настраивает конфиг Апача и подключает к нему модуль библиотеки PHP. В ином случае, при инсталляции по частям, этого не происходит, и нужно dll-ку пхп подключать вручную. Также нужно "сказать" Апачу то, что ему теперь на файлы PHP следует обращать внимание. На эту тему есть масса подробных мануалов, например, этот: [установка и настройка Apache+PHP](http://www.php5.ru/study/install).

Comment: Это вы говорите, чтобы я там в текстовом файле подправил на .php?
Вы про это?

Comment: нее,там, в httpd.conf, необходимо дописать директиву:
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php 
что позволит апачу обрабатывать файлы PHP.
А также добавить php в директиву DirectoryIndex.

Comment: Да переправил.
Все работает.